# Proper use of "has been" versus "have been" after plural reference

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

What is the actual "rule," and which one is correct?

> Ports 10-20 have been or has been opened.

I strongly believe that "have been" is correct. I do not however remember the "rule," so I cannot explain why it is correct.

Can anyone give me some foundation to build my case, please?

Comment: "general reference"

Answer (score 4):

Plural subjects (*ports*) take plural verbs (*have*).  I don’t understand the question.

Comment: You seem to have understood it perfectly. :)